# How to export a table to CSV?

Tags: reactjs, csv, html-table, export-to-csv, antd

I have a table with expandable rows that contain another table. It has been rendered using a library called antd.
I want to export the table along with the expandables as a CSV file. The table :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one approach you can use [react-csv](https://github.com/react-csv/react-csv)([@NPM](http://%20https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-csv)) to export antd table data.

You can use a `CSVLink` by setting the table data to the element.

Example:

```
<CSVLink
  filename={"TableContent.csv"}
  data={data}
  className="btn btn-primary"
>
  Download csv
</CSVLink>
```

Here you can find a [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-black-w559n?file=/index.js) as a minimal working example.

---

**Edit:**

For nested tables usage you can combine the table data with the needed nested table data to export all data in one file.

E.g.:

```
  data.forEach(element => {
    exportedData.push(element);
    nestedData.forEach(element => exportedData.push(element));
  });
```

with the depending csv-link

```
      <CSVLink
        filename={"TableContent.csv"}
        data={exportedData}
        className="btn btn-primary"
      >
```

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-knuth-ey4ne?file=/index.js) for nested Table data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was looking for something that can show the expandable rows as well. I want the products in the expandable to be present below every record in the csv file.

Comment: Have you check the link? The content of the expandable rows are in the exported csv file. Maybe you want to export `nested tables`?

Comment: Right, I want the nested data too. Thanks for that link, I have implemented that but the nested data is just showing [Object]. I wanted that to show up.